# Markov-chain properties

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I have some questions about a Markov-chain $(X_n)$ on a finite state-space $S$ with transition matrix $P$. A function $f:S\rightarrow\mathbb R$ is a columns vector and $Pf$ therefore a matrix multiplication. Now there are three points I am not aware of:

- $\mathbb E^x$ means that $X_0=x\in S$. Then it holds that $[Pf](x)=\mathbb E^xf(X_1)$

  I honestly do not see where this comes from.
- Consider an arbitrary function $g:S\rightarrow\mathbb R$. Then $g(X_n)$ is $\sigma(X_n)$-measurable and $g(X_n)$ is $\mathcal F_n$-measurable where $\mathcal F_n=\sigma(X_k:0\le k\le n)$
- For fixed $f:S\rightarrow \mathbb R$ the process $M_n=f(X_n)-f(X_0)-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}[(P-I)f](X_k)$ is a martingale with respect to the filtration $\mathcal F_n$

I do not see why this should be true because if $Pf\le f$ then $\mathbb E[f(X_{n+1})|\mathcal F_n]$ is a supermartingale

Comment: why must you have $Pf\leq f$ (i.e. f is a superharmonic function)? also a supermartingale may still be a martingale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) is obvious. Think about it. write out the matrix $P$ and $f$ and multiply them. what is the expression for each term of the result?

I think for the row corresponding to $x$, it is $\sum_y P_{xy}f(y)$

Convince yourself, this is that the same as $E^xf(X_1)$.

(2) why dont you just check the martingale property the same way you check a simple symmetric random walk on Z is a martingale? Can you not see how part 1 is connected to this?

Comment: Sorry for my late answer. You have any idea for the second one also? I mean the second point. It seems to be clear that $g(X_n)$ is measurable because of the first point, but how to write it down formally? For the thirs point is only the sum not clear to me, how can I simplify $\mathbb E[\sum_{k=0}^{n}[(P-I)f](X_k)| \mathcal F_n]$

Comment: You want to condition on $\mathcal{F}_{n-1}$. Note X1, X2, X3,...,Xn-1